# How to pass a String-type cursor variable in REPLACE function?

Tags: sql-server, cursor

My query is like:

```
table_name
    _____________________________________
    ID        MailsTo
    101       qwui@gmail.com,cbej@gmail.com,,ojr@gmail.com
    102       jkdj@hotmail.com,,jdjd@outlook.com,,kljm@gmail.com
    103       qwerty@gmail.com,ieury@sify.com,,jkdjhd@yahoo.com
```

As you can see here the `MailsTo` format is not correct as rows contain `,,` instead of single `,`. So how can I update all rows and replace `,,` to `,`?

I have made a cursor to `REPLACE('@MailsTo', ',,', ',')`  --This would be wrong.

**But now my problem is how to pass a String-type variable into such syntax?
**

Can anyone help me with the UPDATE statement of the cursor?

Comment: just pass `REPLACE(@MailsTo, ',,', ',')` but why you need a cursor for this a simply update statement should do the trick.

Comment: When I have more than 100 rows of data how can just UPDATE with REPLACE function would work? I need a cursor to fetch each row and UPDATE. Can you give me the code for it?
Thanks and  I will try what u said..

Comment: update <tablename> set MailTo=REPLACE('@MailsTo', ',,', ',')

Comment: Nitu Bansal, That'd be wrong as it will consider @MailsTo itself as a string.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET MailsTo = REPLACE(@MailsTo,',,',',')
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add  "where ID = @ID "

Comment: No, I did not forget that.

Comment: Did you fetch@MailsTo in your cursor? if no try this

Comment: UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET MailsTo = REPLACE(MailsTo,',,',',') where  ID = @ID